# How to delete Flower and Square Brackets in data for R

Tags: r

I am having the data in below format

```
{abcd} {efgh} {higk}
[lmnop] [qrst] [uvwx]
```

I want to delete flower and square brackets in the data frame and get cleaned data as below

```
abcd efgh higk
lmnop qrst uvwx
```

Seeking help

Answer (score 1):

We can use `[[:punct:]]`

```
df1$col1 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", df1$col1)
df1$col1
#[1] "abcd efgh higk"  "lmnop qrst uvwx"
```

Or specifically

```
gsub("[][]|[{}]", "", df1$col1)
#[1] "abcd efgh higk"  "lmnop qrst uvwx"
```

---

Another option is `rm_bracket` from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
sapply(rm_bracket(df1$col1, c("square", "curly"), extract = TRUE), paste, collapse=' ')
#[1] "abcd efgh higk"  "lmnop qrst uvwx"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("{abcd} {efgh} {higk}", "[lmnop] [qrst] [uvwx]"
 )), .Names = "col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, this helps a lot :)